# Incorrect eigenvalues with cgeev

Tags: fortran, lapack, eigenvalue

I have written the following code to get eigenvalues and determinant of the matrix in fortran with the use of cgeev:

```
SUBROUTINE CDETS(CS,CW,CDET,N)
IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A,B,D-H,O-Z)
IMPLICIT COMPLEX*16 (C)
DIMENSION CW(*),CS(N,*)
ALLOCATABLE :: CWK(:), WK(:), CWL(:,:),CWR(:,:)

ALLOCATE (WK(2*N),CWK(10*N),CWL(N,N),CWR(N,N))
CALL CGEEV('N','N',N,CS,N,CW,CWL,N,CWR,N,CWK,10*N,
  &         WK,INFO)

DEALLOCATE (WK,CWK,CWL,CWR)
CDET = 1.D0
DO i=1,N
  CDET = CDET*CW(i)
ENDDO
END SUBROUTINE
```

And this simple program to check it:

```
PROGRAM TESTDET
  IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A,B,D-H,O-Z)
  IMPLICIT COMPLEX*16 (C)
  DIMENSION :: CS(2,2), CW(2)
  CS(1,1)=(1.D0,1.D0)
  CS(1,2)=1.D0
  CS(2,1)=0.D0
  CS(2,2)=1.D0
  CALL CDETS(CS,CW,CDET,2)
  PRINT *, CW(1)
  PRINT *, CW(2)
END
```

And I get the following quite confusing results:

```
 (  0.0000000000000000     ,  1.0000000000000000     )
 (  1.2828908559913808E-319,  7.6130689002776223E-317)
```

What is the matter here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong procedure.  The argument types between `cgeev` and `zgeev` are the same but differ in kinds.  For `zgeev`, the array `RWORK` is of type and kind of `double precision` and the arrays `A`, `VL`, `VR`, `W`, and `WORK` are `complex*16`.  For `cgeev` the types and kinds, respectively are `real` and `complex`.

You are implicitly typing reals as `real*8`, which are double precision in a non-portable fashion.  Likewise your complex variables are typed as `complex*16`.  Your variables match the argument list of `zgeev`, which is why it works for you and `cgeev` doesn't.   To use `cgeev` change your implicit types to `real` and `complex` and you'll find `cgeev` now works and `zgeev` does not.

From the BLAS naming conventions:

> Every routine in the BLAS library comes in four flavors, each prefixed by the letters S, D, C, and Z, respectively. Each letter indicates the format of input data:
>
> - S stands for single-precision (32-bit IEEE floating point numbers),
> - D stands for double-precision (64-bit IEEE floating point numbers),
> - C stands for complex numbers (represented by pairs of 32-bit IEEE floating point numbers),
> - Z stands for double complex numbers (represented by pairs of 64-bit IEEE floating point numbers)

For your double precision complex variables, you'll need to use the `Z` variants of functions rather than `C`.

Answer (score -3):

I found a way to fix this, but **cgeev** seems to be broken. If you replace **cgeev** with another lapack routine **zgeev** it works perfectly. Most pleasant part is I had to change only one letter.

Comment: `cgeev` ain't broken, it's to be used when the complex numbers have 32 bit components, `zgeev` is for complex arguments with 64-bit components.  You didn't read the documentation carefully enough. The routine naming used by Lapack follows the convention established in BLAS, using the first character to indicate the type of argument required.  See, for example, https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/521147